LTspice's bv unexpected output
I am using 2 behavioral sources in LTspice, forming a comparator with hysteresis:

Below the 2 bvs is a deadtime circuit using LTspice's buffer and AND gate elements.
I want to use b4 as an ideal comparator, with (almost) instant transitions and +-12 V supplies. v(VR1P) - V(VR1N) is the voltage at the inverting input and v(REF) is the voltage at the non-inverting input. V(REF) is generated with B2.
The following is simulation result:

As can be seen there are some weird slopes on B2's output (REF) long before B4 even enters transition.
Why is this?
edit:
There is no such behavior when a model of a real world comparator is used instead:



I also use black background to save on eye-strain, but with one pixel wide lines, the graphs becomes hard to read when scaled down. Can you switch to white background and/or make the lines wider? It's under Tools -> Control panel -> Waveforms -> Data trace width.

Also, what's your simulation maximum time step setting?

Hi winny, thanks for the suggestions, I have changed the line widths to 2px which does look better. The strange behavior is gone when max. time step is set to 5us. The max. timestep parameter was not set in previous simulation runs, and I do not know what the default is

As hinted to in the comments, without chaining maximum time-step, LTspice will more or less try to accomplish a solution with as few time steps as possible as long as it reaches a valid solution. With ideal sources and default logic, the behavior of the circuit is easily solved. As you noted with the real comparator, there is more "stuff" to be computed and the time step gets smaller to accomplish this.
For a given clock frequency and all standard logic components (fast to simulate), I'd recommend you to use 1/100f, where f is your clock or fastest signal, as maximum time step to force reasonable behavior. If it takes too long, you can increase it, but just beware of the slight inconsistencies around each toggle.
Happy simlulating!
